# How to force ICMP to run through TOR?

Tags: networking, tor, ping, protocol

As far as I know, ping send ICMP echo request to host. And ICMP is the layer 3 of OSI model.

But TOR use TCP , which is the layer 4 of OSI model.

So ping can't be run through TOR **normally**.

But here is the question, How can I run ping requests through TOR **by force**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  As you say, ICMP is not TCP.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TransportIPnotTCP

Comment: I know `ICMP` is different from `TCP` and TOR documents says `ICMP` (for example ping) cannot be run  through TOR *normally*. But my question is how to force ping through TOR // Can you help me for this

Comment: The answer is that you can't. It has no mechanisms for transporting ICMP data. If you modify your client to accept it, you can be assured that the next hop will not accept it - because it is not running your modified software.

Answer (score -1):

httptunnel might be able to do it, but you need a httptunnel server at the other end of the tor connection to convert the tcp to icmp.  if not, it should be possible to write a program to do it, but it would have to be at the other end of the tor connection.  it would not be anonymous.

Comment: This can't pass ICMP either.  Tor simply **does not handle** ICMP traffic.